# Uncertainty principle, statistical approach

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem

I have a question about quantum uncertainty, let's say we have a system in the state $\psi=c_0\space|0\rangle \space+\space c_1|1\rangle\space+...$. I understand that if we measure the system, we will always measure some of the eigenstates/values with the probability $|c_n|^2$. So we take a **large** number of measurements of the same system, and calculate the sample mean and the sample variance of those measurements, both of which should be close to the real mean and variance. So that sample variance tells us how accurate we can measure the state of the system, because the measurements will be dispersed, and therefore we can not pin a exact state/value to the that particular system, is that what the uncertainty principle is all about ?

Comment: Yes, and moreover the uncertainty principle gives you a lower bound of the product of the position and momentum variances: $\sigma \hat{\sigma} \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$. This bound relates more generally the variances of a function and its Fourier transform.

Comment: You are welcome. I added a small development in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the uncertainty principle tells you that, and gives you even more: a lower bound of the product of the position and momentum variances: $$\sigma\hat{\sigma} ≥ \frac{\hbar}{2}.$$ This bound relates more generally the variances of a function and its Fourier transform.

Regarding the **large** number of measurements, by the strong law of numbers, the mean value and the variance of your observations will converge almost surely to the mean value and the variance of the observed law, as long as they are both finite, see for example [Sample variance converge almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243348/sample-variance-converge-almost-surely).